# Проблема с кодировкой в названии файла PHP

Tags: php, html, кодировка

## Проблема с кодировкой php

Когда я создаю файл он вместо привет.php создает какой-то РїСЂРёРІРµС‚.php тем самым пытается открыть файл привет.php а не находит его, а вместо привет.php лежит этот файл лежит с ужасным названием РїСЂРёРІРµС‚.php
Вот картинка:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6D803swV1Fcekh5bGlmWnRsSEU

```html
 <form action="data.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="title" required maxlength="30" minlength="3">
  <br>
  <textarea name="val"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
```

```html
<?php 
 $title = $_POST["title"];
 $val = $_POST["val"];
 
 file_put_contents($title.".php", "\xEF\xBB\xBF" . $val);
 
 echo "Ваша страничка создана. <a href = \"".$title.".php\">Перейти</a>";
 
 ?>
```

Comment: лазил по стаку и php.net ничего не нашел.

Comment: Не надо создавать файлы с именами имеющими коды символов выше x7F. Если вам нужны такие имена, то храните имена в базе, а файлы именуйте с помощью функции md5, sha1 и т.п. от реальных имен.

Comment: Перед переменной `$title`  пропишите `header('Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8')`;

Comment: @Visman это верно, лучше использовать только именование с базовым латинским алфавитом, но просто интересно помочь автору решить эту задачу на тех условиях, которые были поставлены в вопросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите, какая у вас кодировка страницы и в какой кодировке данные поступают в PHP-скрипт. Имеет место несовпадение кодировок. Что-то мне подсказывает, что в PHP данные поступают в ASCII-формате.

Установите в файле .htaccess кодировку UTF-8:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
php_value default_charset "utf-8"
```

И в коде HTML-страницы:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: к сожалению не помогло

Comment: @Duoxx попробуйте поэкспериментировать с iconv("windows-1251", "utf-8", $str); еще можно создать файл через fopen(), посмотрите какой будет вывод.

Comment: @Duoxx напишите, в какой кодировке сам файл php и какой заголовок у html. какая у вас система?

Comment: не подскажете как c помощью  iconv перенести в кодировку utf-8 with bom

Comment: @Duoxx iconv конвертирует только строку, а bom - это заголовок файла в кодировке UTF.

Comment: извините, а как сменить кодировку самого файла а не строки.

Comment: Вверху  приложил ссылку на картинку (imgur не захотел работать)

Comment: ну ладно давайте еще один вариант если не получится, помечу как ответ.

Comment: @Duoxx кодировку файла меняем в любом продвинутом текстовом редакторе (например, Notepad++)

Comment: @Duoxx в Notepad++ это Кодировки -> Преобразовать

Comment: @Duoxx но тут дело не в кодировке самого файла, а в том как его интерпретирует операционная система. попробуйте записать "привет" в сам файл, как там будет с кодировкой?

Comment: Maslenikov в самом файле внутри все нормально

Comment: тогда видимо дело в том, как обрабатывает название операционка. попробуйте протестировать установку кириллического названия на linux системе.